# Neo4j - Get collection of nodes along with relation properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes 'member' and 'book'. Member and Book are linked with "ISSUED_TO" relation.
Now, when fetching members I can get a list of all books issued to member using Collect.

I need to extend above query further -
My "ISSUED_TO" relation has one attribute "Issue_Date".

What I need is each members books list along with the Issue_Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provides information for fetching collection of multiple columns

[Fetch multiple columns as collection](https://dzone.com/articles/neo4j-collecting-multiple)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Neo4j 3.1+, you can use [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-map-projection) to include the issue date along with the book's properties:

```
match (b:Book)-[r:ISSUED_TO]->(m:Member)
return m, collect(b {.*, Issue_Date:r.Issue_Date}) as booksIssued
```

Comment: How would i do this if one book was assigned to multiple Members. I have `(Customer)-[:PHONE_NUMBER]->(PhoneNumber)` I want to collect customers for a condition and get all of their phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified this dataset with additional relationships, the query remains the same.

[image]

Assuming you have a relationship attribute by name "issue_date" on the existing relationship, you may compose your query as....

[OLD VERSION]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No. This is not what is required - All the books issued to member 1 can have different issue date.
The expected result can be 
Member 1
             Book1           01-01-2017
             Book2           05-01-2017
             Book3           05-01-2017
Member 2
             Book1           07-12-2016
             Book5           12-01-2017

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
With the query, result shows member gets repeated.
If you remove the r.issue_date and apply - collect(b) result shows per member books issued.
Expecting similar result but along with book the date of issue.

The new result shown should be grouped by member.